# how to set legend or colors on the charts consistent?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I created multiple highcharts in loop and give different colors based on data, but when multiple charts are created their color are not setting consistently. The legend or colors on the charts are not consistent (kiwi vs apple colors across charts).

I have a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7xzjwesr/6/

```
const initialSeries = [{
  name: 'image1',
  data: [
    ['kiwi', 14.6666666667],
    ['apple', 43.0277777778],
    ['orange', 22.6842105263],
  ]

},
];

const parsedData = initialSeries.map(s => ({
    name: s.name,
    data: s.data.map(d => [d[0].toString(), d[1]])
}));


Highcharts.chart('container0', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
  },
  xAxis: {
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  colors: ["#058DC7", "#50B432", "#ED561B", "#DDDF00"],
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
                    colorByPoint: true,
                  },
  },
  series: parsedData
});
const initialSeries2 = [ {
  name: 'image2',
  data: [
    ['banana', 52.9565217391],
    ['apple', 57.5806451613]
  ]

},];

const parsedData2 = initialSeries2.map(s => ({
    name: s.name,
    data: s.data.map(d => [d[0].toString(), d[1]])
}));


Highcharts.chart('container1', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
  },
  xAxis: {
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  colors: ["#058DC7", "#50B432", "#ED561B", "#DDDF00"],
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
                    colorByPoint: true,
                  },
  },
  series: parsedData2
});

const initialSeries3 = [ {
  name: 'image3',
  data: [
    ['kiwi', 409.0952380952],
['banana', 31.4495412844],
['apple', 89.6794871795],
['orange', 27.1818181818],
 ['chiku', 5.9166666667]
  ]
},];

const parsedData3 = initialSeries3.map(s => ({
    name: s.name,
    data: s.data.map(d => [d[0].toString(), d[1]])
}));


Highcharts.chart('container2', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
  },
  xAxis: {
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  colors: ["#058DC7", "#50B432", "#ED561B", "#DDDF00"],
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
                    colorByPoint: true,
                  },
  },
  series: parsedData3
});
const initialSeries4 = [ {
  name: 'image4',
  data: [
   ['banana', 2352.1],
   ['apple', 28.7096774194]
  ]
},];

const parsedData4 = initialSeries4.map(s => ({
    name: s.name,
    data: s.data.map(d => [d[0].toString(), d[1]])
}));


Highcharts.chart('container3', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
  },
  xAxis: {
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  colors: ["#058DC7", "#50B432", "#ED561B", "#DDDF00"],
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
                    colorByPoint: true,
                  },
  },
  series: parsedData4
});
const initialSeries5 = [{
  name: 'image5',
  data: [
   ['kiwi', 376.6538461538],
['banana', 469.8646616541],
['apple', 59.2481977343],
['chiku', 229.9]
  ]
}];

const parsedData5 = initialSeries5.map(s => ({
    name: s.name,
    data: s.data.map(d => [d[0].toString(), d[1]])
}));


Highcharts.chart('container4', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
  },
  xAxis: {
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  colors: ["#058DC7", "#50B432", "#ED561B", "#DDDF00"],
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
                    colorByPoint: true,
                  },
  },
  series: parsedData5
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the color consistency for each point, you should define it in the data config: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.color

To set the legend color you should define a color for the whole series: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.color